# unnecessarily computed property ['@media (max-width:780px)'] found no-useless-computed-key

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a static website using react but it is showing this error?

[image]

Answer (score 12):

From the [ESlint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-computed-key):

> It's unnecessary to use computed properties with literals such as:
>
> `var foo = {["a"]: "b"};`
>
> The code can be rewritten as:
>
> `var foo = {"a": "b"};`

Therefore, you should remove all the square brackets in your code.

```
'@media (max-width: 780px)': {
        paddingBottom: "1rem"
    }
```

Comment: This is solution